# In Laravel 3l, I want to get results using Eloquent from a has_many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have 3 tables:

Invites, Nests and Users.

Invites have the nest_id.
Nests have the user_id

I want to get all the users which have the same nest_id. How do I do this in elequent?

The models have a has_many relationship

---

I am trying to do this in the controller:

```
$users = User::with('invite')->where('invites.nest_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

---

I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invites.nest_id' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `invites`.`nest_id` = ?

Bindings: array (
  0 => '2',
)
```

---

It is saying I do not have a nest_id column, but I do.

---

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

public static $table = 'users';
public static $accessible = array('username', 'email', 'picture', 'password');

public function nest()
{
    return $this->has_many('Nest');
}

    public function invite()
{
     return $this->has_many('Invite');
}
```

---

```
class Nest extends Eloquent
{

public static $table = 'nests';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('User');
}

public function idea()
{
    return $this->has_many('Idea');
}

public function invite()
{
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Invite');
}
```

Comment: It would help if you post your models, specifically nest and user.

Comment: Thanks William, just added...

Answer (score 1):

Laravel relationships do not use joins, so the other tables in the relationship are not accessible.  For relationships involving a "many" this usually works out more efficient.  It does mean you have to think about things like this backwards - you need the users of the Invites who have the given Nest.

```
$invites = Invite::with('user')->where('nest_id', '=', $nest_id);
foreach ($invites as $invite)
{
    $invite->user;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Always seem to overthink the problem. Your comment about thinking 'backwards' is really helpful. Thanks Phil. Laravel is a pleasure to work with. Hope more people adopt.

Comment: If this answer helped you you should mark it as the correct answer user2038291. :)